# Unexpected output range for OPT101 after trimming dark output voltage

Tags: photodiode

I have connected a Rext and Cext to change the responsivity to a bandwidth of 6kHz on the [TI OPT101](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt101.pdf) as in figure 18. Pin 2 (-IN) is left floating and pin 1 and 3 (Vs and -V) are at 5V and 0V respectively.

I then connected pin 8 (the anode of the diode) to a negative voltage, -1.2V, as per the dark output voltage trimming in the datasheet (depicted in figure 18). I did this to offset the measuring range of the diode and subtract the ambient light from the blinking signal that I want to measure. This works, for the same conditions my signal is not saturated anymore due to the addition of the ambient light. Pin 5 (Vo) however is now ranging between 4.4V (as before the dark output trimming) and -1V. How does it go to this negative voltage? I would expect it to go to 0V since that is what the amplifier can minimally supply.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you got connected to pin 3, the negative supply? The offset adjustment circuit in Fig. 17 shows pin 3 to be connected to a negative voltage, presumably to accommodate a slightly negative non-inverting input potential, which would otherwise be outside the amplifier's common-mode input voltage range. And also presumably to allow the output to operate around zero.

Comment: @SimonFitch pin 3 is connected to ground. In the pin functions section (5) of the datasheet it says that it can be connected to ground or a negative voltage. I am fine with the opamp not being able to match 0V, but a voltage slightly above.

Comment: The permissible input voltage range for that op-amp does go right down to the negative supply, but if you "accidentally" drop below that, anything could happen. I suggest you try powering it with -5V or something significantly negative at pin 3, just to see if the problem goes away. At the very least we can rule it out.